# How to paste text from clipboard into selected textbox using a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am relatively new to c# but I am currently creating a Windows Form that has an editor window. I'm struggling with the Paste button though as I have 2 textbox fields, one for the title of the note and one for the note itself. I'm wanting to be able to paste from the clipboard into either textbox.

I have tried using if statements based on  `noteText.Focused` and `titleText.Focused` but obviously this doesn't work as the Paste button becomes focused as soon as you click it.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: So the question is about getting clip board data or getting focused textbox?

Comment: Simply store the last foused textbox in a class level __variable__.

Comment: The question is about getting the clipboard data and pasting it into the 'last focused' textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local variable and save last focused textBox in it.

```
//subscribe both textBoxes with same GotFocus event handler
textBox1.GotFocus += textBox_GotFocus;
textBox2.GotFocus += textBox_GotFocus;

//local variable
TextBox lastSelected;

//GotFocus
private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save last Selected textBox
    lastSelected = sender as TextBox;
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //on click get value from clipboard
    if(lastSelected != null)
        lastSelected.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the text box where you want to paste the clipboard data and write these codes in the button.

```
    private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtvalue.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        btn_paste.Text = "Pasted";
            
    }
```

you can replace the txtvalue and btn_paste with your own textbox and button name ;)