# How paste text from clipboard to the cursor area in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

How paste text from clipboard to the cursor area in a textbox?
With code below we can change entire text of textbox :

```
 radTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

But what about pasting on cursor area?

Comment: Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416454/how-to-paste-text-in-textbox-current-cursor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paste text from clipboard into selected textbox using a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816915/how-to-paste-text-from-clipboard-into-selected-textbox-using-a-button)

Comment: It's not dup. The answer below is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
radTextBox1.Paste(Clipboard.GetText());
```

`Paste` inserts your new text at the current cursor position. If your textbox has highlighted text, `Paste` will replace the hightlighted text with your new text. Here are the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.paste?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: This is true if by 'cursor' op means the insertion point. If he means the mouseposition, a call to `GetCharIndexFromPosition` first, would help..